# Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, pyodbc, netezza, unixodbc

I'm trying to access to IBM Netezza database using pyodbc. I'm using unixODBC2.3.7

odbcinst.ini

```
[NetezzaSQL]
Driver           = /usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so
Setup            = /usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so
APILevel         = 1
ConnectFunctions = YYN
Description      = IBM Netezza ODBC driver
DriverODBCVer    = 03.51
DebugLogging     = false
LogPath          = /tmp
UnicodeTranslationOption = utf8
CharacterTranslationOption = all
PreFetch         = 256
Socket           = 16384
```

I get this error: 
**pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")**

I tried to debug it and i found a missing shared library link: **libcom_err.so.2 => not found**

> ldd /usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f9d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7e1b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7df8000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7df2000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7dd4000)
libssl.so.10 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libssl.so.10 (0xf7d71000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0xf7bbe000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0xf7b18000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf792b000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f9e000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xf78f0000)
libcom_err.so.2 => not found
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xf78bf000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf78a6000)
libcom_err.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib/../lib/libcom_err.so.3 (0xf78a3000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/local/nz/lib/../lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xf789a000)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Ryuuk What's the output of: `yum provides /lib/libcom_err.so.2`?

Comment: @mustaccio, My question is how can i fix this library link.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, "No Matches found"

Answer (score 0):

Try to resolve the problem as described at the link below.
[installing Puredata Linux client on RHEL 6.5 VM client](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/installing-puredata-linux-client-rhel-65-vm-client)

> **Problem**
>
> Puredate INSTALL Linux Client for linux (VM running RHEL 6.x
>
> **Symptom**
>
> installing 32bit client on 64 bit Linux RHEL VM Cause
>
> ./nzds:error while loading shared libraries: libcom_err.so.2".
>   libcom_err.so.2 => not found
>   libcom_err.so.3 =>
>   /usr/local/nz/bin/./../lib/../lib/libcom_err.so.3 (0x00d7e000)
>
> **Environment**
>
> RHEL 6.x
>
> **Diagnosing The Problem**
>
> yum provides libcom_err.so.2
>
> **Resolving The Problem**
>
> yum install e2fsprogs-libs

Comment: Actually i"m using nz-linuxclient-v7.2.1.9-P1.tar.gz, and the missing library is libcom_err.so.2 and not libcom_err.so.3. I tried to find this library in lib64 and lib but i can't find it.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response, actually there is an error with the latest version that i used, so i used another version, and it works fine. thank you